# Gaussian Shell for a non-uniformly charged insulator

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

If I've already found the total charge for an insulating sphere of non-uniform charge, and I want to find the field inside the sphere, can I just set my Gaussian surface to be the surface of that same sphere (so I don't have to bother with a new integral for a smaller Gaussian sphere)?

My reasoning is that insulators don't have a discontinuity in the field at the boundary, so the field at the surface should be the same as the field inside the sphere, potentially.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the field at the surface then sure, take the Gaussian sphere the surface itself.
But if you want to find the field inside the sphere then the Gaussian sphere needs to be taken at a arbitrary distance x inside the sphere and then first find the charge enclosed in it with another integral.

Answer (score 0):

Gauss's law is always true, but it is only useful with a spherical charge if the distribution is spherically symmetrical (the charge density may vary with the radius, but not with the angle).